# How to make Alt-tab app window respective to which screen the App is on

Tags: windows-11, alt-tab

Let's say I have two monitors. `Monitor 1` and `Monitor 2`

I have **Chrome** & **Discord** open in `Monitor 1`, and **File Explorer** & **Terminal** open in `Monitor 2`. Normally, Windows will show all the tabs open when pressing `Alt+Tab`, I want it to show respective to the screen it is in.

So Pressing `Alt+Tab` will show File Explorer and Terminal in `Monitor 2` and Chrome & Discord in `Monitor 1`.

*[Using windows 11]*

Demonstration:
[Demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk7MF.png)